# Jquery autocomplete with response, as filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Below i have some code, which works strange, i mean, it does nothing, i think that :contains function has some issue

```
$(".search").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    appendTo: ".autocomplete",
    minLength:3,

    response: function(event, ui) {
        var content =  ui.content[0].label;
        $.each($('.auto-sort'), function() {
            var t = $(this);
            if (("t:contains(content)")) {
                return;
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Mainly, nothing happens when i type something in input field. I want to have items, that have part of content var in text.

If i reverse some lines of code, this code filters all items:

```
$(".search").autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
appendTo: ".autocomplete",
minLength:3,

response: function(event, ui) {
    var content =  ui.content[0].label;
    $.each($('.auto-sort'), function() {
        var t = $(this);
        if (("t:contains(content)")) {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
        } else {
           return;
        }
    });
},
});
```

Now this above works, but it selects all items, for example if i type "tes" to input fields, all .auto-sort items are hidden, but those which don't contain content text, shoudl be visible.

Where is the problem?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The key to sorting, is to change filter logic to:

```
if($(this).is(':contains('+content+')'))  {
```

Also, to make :containes case insensitive:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
        return function( elem ) {
            return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        };
    });
```